# MDT unable to PXE boot

Tags: windows, mdt

I use an MDT server for PXE boot to image my PC's. Havent had any issues with my process for years. One of my field techs ordered a touch panel for one of our offices instead of the regular PC we install. I had it shipped to me for imaging. Well, this company uses SATA1 instead of SATA0 and it is hard coded with no way to change it in the BIOS. I know, this is so stupid, never seen this is my 22 years in IT.

So, when I try and PXE boot it, it wont detect the drive because it isnt SATA1 as far as I can tell. I have tried everything, I have all the drivers in MDT and set to use to image it and it still fails everytime saying no media detected.

I have tied legacy boot, UEFI and Legacy boot, just UEFI, every combination I can think of to get it to work and it just fails.

I shipped it back to have it investigated and they told me that their engineers can PXE boot it with zero issues. I asked them if they could maybe show me their settings and help me out, and they told me the boilerplate  "Due to policies we are not allowed to do that" why not? its just settings.

Has anyone seen this issue before? How did you resolve it?

Thank you.

I have tied legacy boot, UEFI and Legacy boot, just UEFI, every combination I can think of to get it to work and it just fails.

reseated the drive as well.